# Panda-Column as index for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

How can I use a panda row as index for a numpy array? Say I have

```
>>> grid = arange(10,20)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,5], columns=['i'])
```

I would like to do

```
>>> df['j'] = grid[df['i']]
IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

What is a short and clean way to actually perform this operation?

**Update**

To be precise, I want an additional column that has the values that correspond to the indices that the first column contains: `df['j'][0] = grid[df['i'][0]]` in column `0` etc

expected output:

```
index i j 
    0 0 10
    1 1 11
    2 1 11
    3 5 15
```

**Parallel Case: Numpy-to-Numpy**

Just to show where the idea comes from, in standard python / `numpy`, if you have

```
>>> keys = [0, 1, 1, 5]
>>> grid = arange(10,20)
>>> grid[keys]
Out[30]: array([10, 11, 11, 15])
```

Which is exactly what I want to do. Only that my keys are not stored in a vector, they are stored in a column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a numpy bug that surfaced with pandas 0.13.0 / numpy 1.8.0.

You can do:

```
In [5]: grid[df['i'].values]
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 1, 5])

In [6]: Series(grid)[df['i']]
Out[6]: 
i
0    0
1    1
1    1
5    5
dtype: int64
```

This matches your output. You can assign an array to a column, as long as the length of the array/list is the **same** as the frame (otherwise how would you align it?)

```
In [14]: grid[keys]
Out[14]: array([10, 11, 11, 15])

In [15]: df['j'] = grid[df['i'].values]


In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   i   j
0  0  10
1  1  11
2  1  11
3  5  15
```

Comment: Since I don't really understand the logic that is applying here: How would I affect the index? This now has `df['i']` has an index, but I'd like it to have the index of `df`.

Comment: what are you trying to do? its not really a good idea to index into a numpy array using a pandas structure, because the numpy array doesn't know about indexes or anything.

Comment: I want to add the series to the original dataframe.

Comment: ``df['i'] = grid`` will work as long as the length of the frame is the same as the length of the array

Comment: `df['j'] = pd.Series(grid)[df['i']]` gave me `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`. And `df['j'] = grid` is probably not what you meant - the latter has a completely different size?

Comment: I just added that. And I also slightly adjusted the initial data to make more clear how grid and df['i'] work.

Comment: Your grid is too short, its only 3 elements, your frame is 4. How are you supposed to align it to the frame?

Comment: I extended the question, hopefully it is clearer now.