# If two consecutive rows in an array have the same string in the first column set the remaining entries in the first row to zero

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code so far

```
y= n.genfromtxt('seguedata.txt', dtype=None, usecols = (0,1,2,5),)

for i in y:
if y[i][0] == y[i+1][0]:
    y[i][1]=0
    y[i][2]=0
    y[i][3]=0
```

and I am getting the error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-292d90264548> in <module>()
  1 for i in y:
2     if y[i][0] == y[i+1][0]:
  3         y[i][1]=0
  4         y[i][2]=0
  5         y[i][3]=0

IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

segue data is a large data set with 4 columns where the first column is a string and the other 3 are numbers. If two consecutive rows have the same initial string I want to set the values of the first row to zero.

Thanks

Comment: can it be this bug? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655080/panda-column-as-index-for-numpy-array

Answer (score 2):

Print out `i`:

```
for i in y:
    print(i)
```

you will see they are rows of `y`, not integers. Since `y` is a structured array, `y` can be indexed by integers or column names but not tuples of row values, so `y[i]` raises the error

```
IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

---

To fix the problem with minimal adjustment to your code, you could use

```
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    if y[i][0] == y[i+1][0]:
        y[i][1]=0
        y[i][2]=0
        y[i][3]=0
```

---

Modifying a NumPy array element-by-element should be avoided when possible.
Operating on whole arrays or at least large slices of it will yield better
performance.

In this case, it would be more efficient to find the rows with consecutive equal
values:

```
mask = (y['f0'][1:] == y['f0'][:-1])
```

and then set all the values to zero in each column for the rows where mask is True:

```
mask = np.concatenate([mask, [False]])
for col in y.dtype.names[1:]:
    y[col][mask] = 0
```